# Probability law is invariant under matrix action

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of probability density function $w$ and let $Y = f(X) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $Af(X)=f(AX)$ and $w(X)=w(AX)$ for some real matrix $A$ whose determinant is $\pm1$. Is it true that the probability law of $Y$ is invariant under $A$?

I think it just boils down to a change of variables but I want to make sure I'm doing things properly.

I have for any function $g$

$$\int g(Af(X))w(X)dX=\int g(f(AX))w(AX)dX=\int g(f(U))w(U)|A|^{-1}dU=\int g(f(U))w(U)dU$$

so I conclude that $Af(X)$ and $f(X)$ have same law, right?

Likewise, if $\det A$ were different, then I guess the law of $Af(X)$ is just the law of $f(X)$ scaled by $|\det A^{-1}|=|A|^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.  Just some typos: the third term in the equalities is missing $g$, as in $\int g(f(u))w(u)|A|^{-1}dU$.  The scaling factor you mentioned is also correct; I think you mean $|A|^{-1}=|\det A|^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Indeed, I forgot $g$ and I'm taking the absolute value of the det. My reputation is too low to upvote, sorry for this